# Flutter - Firebase.initializeApp() method doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-chrome

I'm writing a flutter web app with Firebase.

The app is hosting on Firebase now and, to use Firebase Authentication service, I want `Firebase.initializeApp()` to be executed.

But there is a problem as mentioned on title.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const WebLoginApp());
}
```

When the app gets started, it shows only a white screen.

[image]

and also shows error log on DEBUG CONSOLE (case 1)

[image]

OR has break points with error log. (case 2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Without `await Firebase.initializeApp();`, the app works well.

I've found another app I wrote for Firebase test has the same problem but it works well 3 weeks ago.

I've just updated Flutter and Chrome with latest version.

Could you give a hint or a solution?

It will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably forgot the web installation for firebase, check this:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web

and you need `initializeApp` to this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```